# MFC: Address Bar control like Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-explorer

In my MFC app, I'm attempting to make a window that resembles the Windows 7 Open File dialog, but it browses a virtual/fake file system. It doesn't need to be pixel-perfect, but I'd like parity with the native OS dialog where possible.

Probably the most challenging part is the address bar the runs along the top of an Open dialog. The address bar control is also atop all Windows Explorer windows. It shows the folder names that make up your path. It shows and hides buttons when moused over (including an attractive fade animation), changes the active directory when names are clicked, and shows submenus when the triangles between names are clicked. This doesn't seem to correspond to any MFC control (or group of controls). Spy++ shows it as an "AddressDisplay Control" but I can't find much documentation beyond that.

Is there a way to access a control like this, or to mimic it, in MFC? Also, I am not browsing the *real* file system, so I have to be able to tell the control what to display--I can't just point it at C:\ and let the system do the rest.

Here's a picture of the control in question.

[image]

Comment: A picture would be helpful and a little more detail.

Comment: The control is literally atop of every Windows Explorer dialog and File Open dialog. I assume most users here are familiar with it. I've included a picture in case my description is missing the mark.

Comment: Breadcrumb bar.  On Windows 8.1 it is a subclassed custom-drawn ToolbarWindow32.  Microsoft isn't sharing their custom controls anymore.  If you don't want to create your own then you'll have to go shopping.

Comment: Hans, why didn't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think this is one of those controls that Microsoft has decided not to expose to developers through the Feature Pack.  The Feature Pack was developed from the [BCG control library](http://www.bcgsoft.com/).  And, that library contains the control you want.  However, it's not free.  The only other alternative is to code it yourself.

[image: Screen shot from BCG sample]

Comment: Also, if it's using the shell, it would be very hard to get it to show arbitrary non-disk paths.