# Creating a Control Panel Applet similar to built in applets

Tags: mfc, windows-explorer

I have created a Control panel applet. The icon is placed in the control panel. When I double click my icon, it just opens a notepad application.

What I have to implement is, when I double click on my icon, it should open the GUI similar to the UI of other the Control panel (Power options of control panel.)
[image]
My question is, do I need to create a separate windows forms application? or any other way is there?

Comment: You must create shell namespace extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Creating address bar similar to explorer is not possible, since MS has not exposed such control. 
  You can take a look at the following link...
  [MFC: Address Bar control like Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176838/mfc-address-bar-control-like-windows-explorer)